# SQLAlchemy (no ORM): update statement not committing

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have this (anonymized) function in my database module:

```
def fix_publishing_dates(row_id, last_time=None, next_time=None,
    next_index=1, user="python_script"):
  sql = """
  UPDATE
    schema.table
  SET
    last_time = :last_time
  , next_time = :next_time
  , next_index = :next_index
  , col4 = SYSDATE
  , col5 = :user_id
  , is_active = 1
  WHERE
    id = :row_id
  """
  with closing(Session()) as s:
    with s.begin_nested():
      user_id = get_userid_by_name(user)
      args = dict(
          last_time=last_time,
          next_time=next_time,
          next_index=next_index,
          row_id=row_id,
          user_id=user_id,
          )
      s.execute(sql, args)
      s.flush()
    s.commit()
```

For some reason, this is not working.  I query the above table for is_active=1, and I get zero rows.  Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

#### Note

I don't want to use SQLAlchemy ORM and add lots of boilerplate Table classes* for this; I just like using Session() with text queries for the transaction support.

*: nor slow down my startup time with introspection; the network pipe to this database is slow.

#### Edit 1

- I'm using an Oracle 11 database through cx_oracle.
- In case it matters, one of the bound values is sometimes None/
- This code (anonymized differently) also isn't working:

  ```
  def fix_publishing_dates(**kwargs):
    sql = insert_query_here
    user_id = get_userid_by_name(user)
    args = dict(kwargs)
    print "*" * 50
    print "* About to update database with values: {}".format(args)
    print "*" * 50
    result = engine.execute(sql, args)
    print "Row count is:", result.rowcount
    #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
    #s.commit()
  ```

Comment: Which database and what version are you using? Some of them do not allow nested transactions.

Comment: turn on echo=True with create_engine() to see that the SQL you expect is emitted, also you can get the result of s.execute() and see that result.rowcount is nonzero.  the flush() is also entirely superfluous (as is the begin_nested(), really, but perhaps you have something more complex going on IRL)

Comment: I currently only have one function that really needs transactions.  That one's all INSERT statements, and it works just fine with raw SQL and a Session().

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Sessions will manage transactions without using ORM objects. But you can just use the transactions on the engine directly:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(...)
```

Comment: OK well the Session *does* do a transaction, but if you're only emitting raw SQL, there's not much reason to use the Session.   The flush() is unnecessary too.   I'm not sure why the UPDATE is failing originally, however, the with begin_nested() should be committing the inner trans.

Comment: I knew the flush should be unnecessary, but I was getting desperate. :)